# Reducing the distance required to un-maximise window by dragging down

Tags: gnome, window

Is there any way to reduce or remove the distance required to unsnap a window in gnome? In order to un-maximise a window by dragging down, you have to move the mouse cursor about 20 pixels down. This has the effect of making window management feel jerky. Whilst in windows, the window begins to move as soon as the cursor is moved down.

[Here is a video to try and explain what i mean in more detail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4-ZlBgJ9RI)

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04, but KDE has the same problem. XFCE has the desired behaviour, but I'd rather use gnome.

Comment: Very justified concern: indeed the current "metrics" for this action feel clumsy. However, I am afraid this is hard coded. It would be worthy filling this as an issue with the Gnome developers (the window manager Mutter to be more specific).